# S3アクセス時に403Error-RequestTimeTooSkewed

Tags: aws

ec2サーバからS3へhtmlファイルをダウンロードのリクエスト時に403エラーになってしまいます。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.</Message><RequestTime>Thu, 28 Jan 2016 02:48:21 +0900</RequestTime><ServerTime>2016-01-28T02:48:22Z</ServerTime><MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds>900000</MaxAllowedSkewMilliseconds><RequestId>6B2156395568ABEC</RequestId><HostId>qZRQyJAK9SqJp4Vfp79j2T+iTJKgn8ONys1hp49/DeZs8tCfXMNXP8RUgeUw+5UwU7EalEFzGAY=</HostId></Error>
```

調べてみたところ、サーバーとクライアントの時刻のズレのせいという話が出てきたため、
ntpを利用して同期をしてみても解消されません。

```
<RequestTime>Thu, 28 Jan 2016 02:48:21 +0900</RequestTime>
<ServerTime>2016-01-28T02:48:22Z</ServerTime>
```

実際、リクエストとサーバー時刻にも大きな差は無いように見えます。

原因・解決策が分かる方ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> <RequestTime>Thu, 28 Jan 2016 02:48:21 +0900</RequestTime>
> ```

こっちはJSTで、

> ```
> <ServerTime>2016-01-28T02:48:22Z</ServerTime>
> ```

こっちはUTCなので、JSTの時差分の9時間ずれています。

ntpdを普通に動かしただけでは大きなずれは補正されません。